# Xarray - concatenating slices from multiple files

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I'm attempting to concatenate slices of multiple files into one file (initialized by a zeros array) and then write to a nCDF file.  However, I receive the error:

```
arguments without labels along dimension 'Time' cannot be aligned 
because they have different dimension sizes: {365, 30}
```

I understand the error (the isel() changes the size of the dimension to the size of the slice), however I don't know how to correct or circumvent the problem.  Am I approaching this task correctly?  Here's a simplified version of the first iteration:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

i=0

PRCP = np.zeros((365,327,348))

d = xr.open_dataset("/Path")

d = d.isel(Time=slice(0,-1,24))

P = d['CUMPRCP'].values

DinM = P.shape[0]

PRCP[i:i+DinM,:,:] = P

i = i + DinM

PRCPxr = xr.DataArray(PRCP.astype('float32'),dims=[('Time'), 
'south_north', 'west_east']) 

d['DPRCP'] = PRCPxr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by removing the dims=() argument from xr.DataArray(), where it arbitrarily renamed them.